# Getting data from web service using ksoap in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-ksoap2

I'm working on a project, I want to make android application that get data from web service via soap and parse data for using in listview. I'm in trouble with viewing data. Can not see data in logcat via using Log.e(). Thanks in helpings.

My Service is looks link below;
http://jsfiddle.net/gkwuvyzs/

Here is my LayerInformation Class;

```
package com.example.soapservice;
public class LayerInformation {

    private String Adi;
    private String Urli;
    private String Lyr_tipi;
    private String Alani;

    public LayerInformation(){
        super();
    }

    public LayerInformation(String Adi, String Urli, String Lyr_tipi, String Alani){
        super();
        this.Adi = Adi;
        this.Urli = Urli;
        this.Lyr_tipi = Lyr_tipi;
        this.Alani = Alani;

    } 

    public String getISMI() {
        return Adi;
      }

      public void setISMI(String Adi) {
        this.Adi = Adi;
      }

      public String getURL() {
        return Urli;
      }

      public void setURL(String Urli) {
        this.Urli = Urli;
      }

      public String getLAYER_TIPI() {
        return Lyr_tipi;
      }

      public void setLAYER_TIPI(String Lyr_tipi) {
        this.Lyr_tipi = Lyr_tipi;
      }

      public String getALANI() {
        return Alani;
      }

      public void setALANI(String Alani) {
        this.Alani = Alani;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return "Layer [ISMI=" + Adi + ", URL=" + Urli + ", LAYER_TIPI=" + Lyr_tipi
            + ", ALANI=" + Alani + "]";
      }
}
```

And here my mainactivity;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final static String METHOD_NAME = "LayerBilgileri";
    final static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/LayerBilgileri";
    final static String URL = "http://193.34.23.1:84/layerismi/Service1.asmx";
    static String str;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //str = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    }

    public static List<LayerInformation> 
    LayerBilgileri() {
         List<LayerInformation> list = null;
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
         HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
         androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

         try {
              androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
              SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();


              if (response.toString().equals("anyType{}") || response == null) {
                list = null;
              } else {
                SoapObject soapLayerInformationsList = (SoapObject) response.getProperty("LAYERLER");
                // ya da 
                // SoapObject soapLayerInformationsList = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(0);
                list = new ArrayList<LayerInformation>();
                int LayerlerCount = soapLayerInformationsList.getPropertyCount();

                for (int i = 0; i < LayerlerCount; i++) {
                    LayerInformation item = new LayerInformation();
                  SoapObject soapLayerInformations = (SoapObject) soapLayerInformationsList.getProperty(i);

                  if (soapLayerInformations.hasProperty("ISMI")) {
                    item.setISMI(soapLayerInformations.getPropertyAsString("ISMI"));

                  }

                  if (soapLayerInformations.hasProperty("URL")) {
                    item.setURL(soapLayerInformations.getPropertyAsString("URL"));

                  }

                  if (soapLayerInformations.hasProperty("LAYER_TIPI")) {
                    item.setLAYER_TIPI(soapLayerInformations.getPropertyAsString("LAYER_TIPI"));
                  }

                  if (soapLayerInformations.hasProperty("ALANI")) {
                    item.setALANI(soapLayerInformations.getPropertyAsString("ALANI"));
                  }


                  list.add(item);
                }
              }
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              list = null;
            }

        return list;


    }
```

Comment: What u get when u type this Log.d("RESPONSE",response.toString()); in logcat

Comment: Thanks for commenting @sakir, But log can not retrieve any data for me ..log returns null